# Nothing was returned from render. React / Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript and have decided to implement on my personal site for exercise. The layout works great before using typescript. However, even though I am not getting type errors I am getting console errors.

[image: Nothing rreturned from rendered]

Here is the Layout component using styled-components

```
const ContentLayout: React.StatelessComponent<{
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }) => <ContentWrapper>{children}</ContentWrapper>;

export default ContentLayout;
```

Here is the parent component

```
class Master extends React.Component<{ children: any }, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header />
        <ContentLayout>
          <Routes />
        </ContentLayout>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Master;
```

Any thoughts on why this would not render?

Comment: If you make an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) I'll take a look for you.

Comment: is there any InitCloneByTag component in your code?

Comment: Nope, I was able to get it working with reworking it but had to drift away from the typescript. So I just need to read the docs closer.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what you need is solution which allows SASS files to be generated on the fly and also support production builds. I managed to combine a boilerplate code which supports Typescript, Better version of Javascript, ReactJS with SCSS modules. The boilerplate takes care of all the extra stuff needed to setup your app.

I would recommend that you check it out. https://github.com/alishahlakhani/Reactsx-React-TS-SCSS-PWA-Boilerplate